# syntax error when trying to upload xml database to host

Tags: syntax

I'm getting the following error message.

Error

> Static analysis:
> 1 errors were found during analysis.
> The name of the entity was expected. (near "DEFAULT CHARACTER SET" at position 31)

SQL query:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

MySQL said:

> Documentation #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the database name [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-database.html)

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mydatabasename
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: Thanks Derpirscher. I am not a coder. The name of the database (created by WordPress on my Mac) is kindagay.WordPress.2021-04-03.xml

Comment: I suppose the db's name is only `kindagay`. Just replace `mydatabasename` in the above query with whatever you want your database to be named ...